# Do the USB Keyboard wedge barcode reader invokes key event?

Tags: java, gwt, barcode-scanner

I want to change the focus to the next textbox once barcode is scaned using scanner

so do this barcode scanner invokes the key event like keyup so that i may check the length of barcode to determine the barcode is enter and shift the focus to another textbox for scannig another barocde ....

please help me

Comment: @tushar...can u post which barcode API are u using..

Comment: I am not using any barcode API , i am using USB Keyboard wedge barcode scanner which directly puts barcode to the selected textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you just try ? add a keylistener to your textbox and output the keyevents.